# Cleaning up code with plt.subplots in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following data, `df`

```
              OrderCount    OrderAvgSize    AvgDeliverCost  AvgOrderValue   count
Response                    
AmznPrime       12.41           11.46            4.45           10.13        392
Both_Or_None    17.20           6.85             4.07           5.18         1099
Walmart+        24.75           13.45            4.57           9.61         687
```

I used it to create a subplot with the code below:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,5,sharex=True,figsize=(20,5),constrained_layout=True)

ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5 = ax.flatten()

sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.OrderCount, ax=ax1, data=df)
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.OrderAvgSize, ax=ax2, data=df)
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.AvgDeliverCost, ax=ax3, data=df)
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df.AvgOrderValue, ax=ax4, data=df)
sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df['count'], ax=ax5, data=df)

axs = [ax1,ax2,ax3,ax4,ax5]

for i in axs:
  i.grid(zorder=0,alpha=.4)
  i.set_axisbelow(True)
```

My question is: is there a way I can further clean up this code? I feel like there should be a way to use a for loop to graph each subplot and eliminate some lines, but I'm not sure how to go about that with the `ax` and `y=` both being different in each line. Again, I have no trouble producing subplots, but feel as though I may be inefficient in doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `enumerate` on df.columns

Comment: I have never used enumerate before, could you please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,5,sharex=True,figsize=(20,5),constrained_layout=True)

ax = ax.flatten()
col = ["OrderCount", "OrderAvgSize", "AvgDeliverCost", "AvgOrderValue", "count"]

for a, c in zip(ax, col):
    sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df[c], ax=a, data=df)
    a.grid(zorder=0,alpha=.4)
    a.set_axisbelow(True)
```